# MVC edit with an HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase

I have been mostly following this tutorial: http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/

It created a good create view that allows the user to upload an image.

How would I create a similar page that displays the current image file (such as what this shows when the user has selected one in the create view) and still allows the user to select a different image?

```
@model ImageViewModel

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div>
        Name:
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        Image Upload:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageUpload, new { type = "file" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>



public class ImageViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
}
```

As it currently is, this just allows the Name to be changed and a new image to be uploaded. I want it to show the filename of the current image, but I don't know of a way to upload info to the HttpPostedFileBase attribute (database is currently holding the filename/path from create).

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  It sounds like you're asking how to pre-populate the file input on page load with the name of the existing uploaded file?  Most browsers ignore the value field on file inputs so that won't make much sense.

Comment: Another odd bug from not being able to repopulate ImageUpload is that it gets cleared and must be reselected if the ModelState was invalid. I just feel there should be a better way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra property to your ImageViewModel and bind the current filename to that property:

```
public class ImageViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
}
```

In your Edit View just display the FileName property:

```
@model ImageViewModel

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div>
        Name:
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        Current uploaded file:
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FileName)
    </div>
    <div>
        Image Upload:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageUpload, new { type = "file", value = "test" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>

</form>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I was hoping I could just prepopulate ImageUpload. With the other EditorFor, TextBoxFor, etc, they show the data that is prepopulated into them. I was hoping for a solution that would accomplish this with ImageUpload as well.